# Django how to use the List Field, not change to string

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I would like to use the List Field in the mongoDB of Django. However, when I use it to upload the data, the error is **TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not NoneType** So I trackback. I found the built in function can't get the type of data. However, it is **List**.

```
>>type(dataList)
<type 'list'>
```

my table structure is:

```
class USER_Network(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    rows = ListField(models.CharField(max_length =200))
    species = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

my upload is:

```
user_network = USER_Network.objects.create( name=networkname,\
                                            species = speciesId,\
                                            rows = dataList,\
                                            user_id = user)
```

I double checked, the reason is the list.

Comment: Does the content of `dataList` make a difference? Is it possible that you have `None` in the list whole the field only accepts strings?

Comment: I don't think so. Because when I use the unicode(dataList). It works

Comment: Well `unicode(dataList)` converts the list into a string. You should debug by checking the content of your list before passing it.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is not None in the dataList. It is just a List.@sirfz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by MongoDB. MongoDB based Django is different from the normal one.